# Get Telegram Bot to Reply to Specific Message

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am able to sendMessage to a group using the `chat_id` and that works fine, but is not what I'm looking for.

I am trying to make my TG Bot REPLY to a Specific Message in a group. Users can do it normally to other users such as by Right Clicking on a message, clicking reply, and replying. Once this reply has sent, it highlights the original message and shows the reply to it as shown in the image.

[image: imageOne]

I want my bot to do this when it replies to a user but can't figure out how or if it's possible. I'm also not using `python-telegram-bot`. I'm doing custom JSON POST requests.

Answer (score 3):

After sending a message with the [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method, the following data is returned:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123456&text=SO Example
```

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "message_id": 80,
        "from": {
            ...
```

You'll need to *save* the `message_id` somewhere.

Then, use the `reply_to_message_id` parameter from [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), you can reply on that message like so:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123456&text=Reply&reply_to_message_id=80
```

[image]